# URL Pattern Matching in wget

Tags: regex, wget

The pages of a website I want to download all begin with a specific pattern of characters, like this:

www.site.com/1234_1

www.site.com/1234_2

www.site.com/1234_3

et cetera.

Is there a way to tell wget to download only the pages beginning with this sequence? The --noparent option won't work as there are many pages in the same directory that I don't want, and making a url list would be much too tedious in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is from wget help:

```
--accept-regex=REGEX        regex matching accepted URLs
```

So you probably can do this:

```
wget --accept-regex="www\.site\.com\/1234" rest-of-your-command
```

Comment: Can I use the REGEX patterns that I use in Python `re` lib?